# why does rake db:migrate say my development database doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, terminal

I'm typing in the terminal

rake db:migrate

Here's the error Im getting

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
```

Comment: Try to run `rake db:create`.

Comment: Or you can do rake db:setup, which you may want to get to know. It runs some additional tasks. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#setup-the-database

Answer (score 1):

`rake db:migrate` doesn't create database, rather requires it exists.

`rake db:create` creates a database without loading database schema.

Remember you should run `rake db:create` before you can run `rake db:migrate` if you dropped database with `rake db:drop`.